# Read columns of string into lists

Tags: python, string, list

Lets say that I have the following string

```
s = """WaveL         C[0,0].Pow     C[0,0].Pow(s)  C[0,0].Pow(p)  Balance        \n400            0.4411         0.4411         1.7698E-008    0.51322       \n700            0.61133        0.61133        4.0576E-007    0.88026"""

print(s)
> WaveL         C[0,0].Pow     C[0,0].Pow(s)  C[0,0].Pow(p)  Balance    
> 400            0.4411         0.4411         1.7698E-008    0.51322   
> 700            0.61133        0.61133        4.0576E-007    0.88026
```

Now **I would like to get the values of the columns into lists**. It works if I store the string as a text file and then open it using np.genfromtxt(), but I cannot see another simple way (without so much overhead)...

```
with open('temp.text', 'w') as file: file.write(s)
        file.close()


data = np.genfromtxt('temp.text')


row1 = data[1:,0]
row2 = data[1:,1]

os.remove('temp.text')
```

Do you see how I can do it ?

**EDIT:**

Sorry to the guys who answered me of how to get the rows. I actually meant to ask how to get the columns. Sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.splitlines` and `str.split` in a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
s = """WaveL         C[0,0].Pow     C[0,0].Pow(s)  C[0,0].Pow(p)  Balance        \n400            0.4411         0.4411         1.7698E-008    0.51322       \n700            0.61133        0.61133        4.0576E-007    0.88026"""
result = [row.split() for row in s.splitlines()]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['WaveL', 'C[0,0].Pow', 'C[0,0].Pow(s)', 'C[0,0].Pow(p)', 'Balance'],
 ['400', '0.4411', '0.4411', '1.7698E-008', '0.51322'],
 ['700', '0.61133', '0.61133', '4.0576E-007', '0.88026']]
```

---

Update as per comment.

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = """WaveL         C[0,0].Pow     C[0,0].Pow(s)  C[0,0].Pow(p)  Balance        \n400            0.4411         0.4411         1.7698E-008    0.51322       \n700            0.61133        0.61133        4.0576E-007    0.88026"""
result = defaultdict(list)
for row in s.splitlines():
    for i, r in enumerate(row.split()):
        result[i].append(r)

result = {v[0]: list(map(float, v[1:])) for _, v in result.items()}     
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Balance': [0.51322, 0.88026],
 'C[0,0].Pow': [0.4411, 0.61133],
 'C[0,0].Pow(p)': [1.7698e-08, 4.0576e-07],
 'C[0,0].Pow(s)': [0.4411, 0.61133],
 'WaveL': [400.0, 700.0]}
```

Comment: My mistake, sorry! :(( I wrote the wrong question. I updated it now.

Comment: I'd suggest that a structure more like: `{'WaveL':[400, 700], 'C[0,0].Pow':[0.4411, 0.61133], ...}` would suit the OP better.

Comment: @henry. look like you just changed the que.

Comment: @Baldrickk That would also suit me yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How do I make sure that the values are float ?

Comment: `result = {v[0]: list(map(float, v[1:])) for _, v in result.items()}`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on the output to be a numpy array, you can do the following.

```python
s = """ .... """

np.array(s.split('\n', 1)[1])
```

The string is split into lines, but just once. You take the second element of the resulting list and finally convert this string into a numpy array.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the first column, 2nd column, etc. ?

Comment: @henry Have a look into the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing), but basically it is `a[:, n]` for the n-th column of "a".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without any extra libraries, you can extract the header and then iterate through your lines.

```
lines = [l for l in s.splitlines()]
cols={}
for col in lines[0].split(): cols[col]=[]

keys=list(cols.keys())

for i, col in enumerate(lines[1:]):
    for e,i in enumerate(col.split()):
        cols[keys[e]].append(i) #.append(float(i))
```

This would give you a dictionary where you can pick the individual columns:

```
{'WaveL': ['400', '700'],
 'C[0,0].Pow': ['0.4411', '0.61133'],
 'C[0,0].Pow(s)': ['0.4411', '0.61133'],
 'C[0,0].Pow(p)': ['1.7698E-008', '4.0576E-007'],
 'Balance': ['0.51322', '0.88026']
```

This might not be overly efficient if you are dealing with big files, and your best use might be using proper deserialisation (e.g. look at CSV file readers, such as in [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader), [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) - they will most likely be more robust than [genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html))

Comment: Nice answer ! How can I convert the values to float ? Simply  .append(float(i)) ?

Comment: Exactly - I leave it to you to try it out yourself